# Some mysterious stack mechanism in C++

Tags: c++, stack, quicksort

While learning how to write quick sort I came across a certain implementation that is very unclear for me. Here is the beginning of it:

```
void quick_sort_iterative(int start, int end)
{
    range stack[32]; // 1. why 32? why not 2? why not 1024? what is it?
    range * s = stack; // 2. just a simple pointer = an array?
    s->start = start; // 3. are these two values currently on top of the stack?
    s->end = end;
    s++; // 4. how does it work? it's pushing something on the stack?

    // sort as long as there are any ranges [start, end] to sort left
    while (s > stack) // 5. comparing a pointer and an array and it works?
```

Could someone please explain me those 5 things? :) Thank you.

Here is the entire code (the last one on the page, with the descriptions):
[code](https://www.codeplay.com/portal/optimizing-sort-algorithms-for-the-ps3-part-1-quicksort)

Comment: Could you include the entire function in the question? It's difficult to know what things are being used for without the entire function.

Comment: `stack = &stack[0]`. Incrementing the pointer moves the pointer to the next array item. 32 should be enough for anyone :) Although it is possible to construct an array of reasonable size which would require going deeper than 32.

Comment: These are a lot of questions in one question.

Comment: In general any recursive function can be implemented without recursion using an explicit local stack to do what the implicit call stack does in the recursive version. Without seeing more code it's hard to answer all your questions but I suspect that is what is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. Presumably `range` is some object with two integer parameters `start` and `end`. I can't tell much more than that.

1. For whatever reason, the designers of the algorithm believe that they won't need more than 32 fake stack frames.
2. The array decays to a pointer. You can think of this as `&stack[0]`.
3. `s->start` is currently the same as `s[0].start`.
4. `s` now points to `&stack[1]`.
5. The array decays to a pointer. So that is true as long as `s` doesn't point to `&stack[0]`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I was attempting to dig a bit deeper into what that variable actually means in regards to the algorithm. But it looks like the question for number 2 is really just a syntax question.

Comment: In the quicksort algorithm, each "depth" divides the array in 2, so `32` perhaps was chosen because the system had a maximum size of 2^32 for the container being sorted.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: They also switch to insertionSort for sizes less than 55, but that would be my guess as well. That guarantee also requires a  well chosen pivot. Personally, I'd like to see a failsafe call to `insertionSort()` when they run out of fake stack frames.

Comment: `s > stack` also implies that the array is growing down, i.e. the elements with higher indices have lower address. The code is highly architect specific.

Comment: s > stack is initially true because of the sequence s = stack; ... s++; . I assume somewhere later in the code is a s--, and that eventually s is not > stack.

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe just a number picked from their nether region, or perhaps arrived at through careful examination of the maximum stack depth of the algorithm. I'm guessing the former.
2. Any array variable will naturally decay to a pointer when used in a context that requires a pointer.
3. If you consider the first element of the "stack" array to be the top, then yes.
4. Given the assumption in 3 then incrementing the pointer would indeed be moving to the next element down on the stack.
5. See 2. Presumably the loop is decrementing `s` and they want to stop when it reaches the top of the stack again.